# How do I create a multiform GTK App

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Hi I have been playing around with C and Gtk trying to learn a thing or two

Now wondering how do I create an application that has more then one form.

Do I just clear the window out or do I create new windows every time I want to have another form or view.

and does anyone know a good place to learn this type of thing?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. It does not seem like you even tried to google for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your goal is to use one window but change (large parts of) the window contents at times?

The widget you are looking for is [GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html), which is a container that will only show one of its children at a time. You can use a Stack with user visible controls (StackSwitcher) or from your own code.

The Stack was only added in 3.10, so in earlier GTK+ versions you'll need to do the work yourself: Add your "forms" as children of a Box and make sure only one child is shown at a time.

> does anyone know a good place to learn this type of thing?

To find out what kind of widgets you have at your disposal, I suggest reading the fine manual: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/.